# bash script mv command not working

Tags: macos, bash, mv

I'm trying to write a script that renames a file at login in OSX Lion.

Here is my script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin ]; then
    mv ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin ~/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin1
    say "Successful"
else
    say "Unsuccessful"
fi
```

I've created a LoginHook which executes the script. I know it executes at login because the computer speaks when it can finds the "ksadmin" file. I know it finds the "ksadmin" file because the computer says "Successful". I have also manually renamed the file, logged out, back in and the computer says "Unsuccessful".

The problem is that the script doesn't rename "ksadmin" to "ksadmin1". Have I written to command properly?

Any ideas would be great.

Morgan

Comment: You could add, at the end of the mv command, the following: `2>&1 >1 /tmp/mverror` and then check if it's complaining about anything. Maybe even run mv with a -v so you can be sure that it was actually executed

Comment: @Miquel I tried doing both those commands but both seemed to do nothing. There was no file created in the /tmp/ directory and nothing alerted me that the file had been moved.

Comment: @MorganR: if there was no file created, then it did not execute the command.  You should have a file there, even though it might be empty.

Comment: Well, if you ran mv with -v and outputted to a file, and the file was empty... then mv wasn't run at all. Longshot here, but could you replace mv with /bin/mv ? Just in case it's a path issue

Comment: Ah, this is interesting. I changed the command to 2>/mverror and in the file created I see this: "mv: rename /var/root/Library/rest/of/path/ksadmin to /var/root/Library/rest/of/path/ksadmin1: No such file or directory".

Comment: Try replacing the `~` with `/Users/$1/` then?

Comment: You're right, mVChr. I have no idea why it didn't work in the first place, maybe there was an unrelated issue. Thanks for your help guys, I have posted the solution to my question below (edit: it won't let me post it because I'm new to the site, but the solution is in these comments).

Comment: @Miquel: Your command creates a file called "1" in whatever directory is current.

Comment: @MorganR: You should be able to post your answer. Flag your question and ask a moderator for help.

Comment: It didn't work with `~/Library/...` because LoginHook scripts run as root *before* the user session starts (as opposed to things like LaunchAgents and Login Items, which run as the user *after* the session starts).

Answer (score 0):

What are the permissions on ksadmin? If it's read only for your login id and a ksadmin1 already exists, then you may need a mv -f.
Also, you may want to expand "~" to the absolute path. Not sure when exactly your script gets executed but perhaps bash can not yet expand it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to cdarke, Miquel and mVChr for help. The solution to the problem is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ -f /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin ]; then
    mv /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin1
    say "Successful"
else
    say "Unsuccessful"
fi
```

Version I use for deployment:

```
#!/bin/bash
    if [ -f /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin ]; then
        mv /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin /Users/$1/Library/Google/GoogleSoftwareUpdate/GoogleSoftwareUpdate.bundle/Contents/MacOS/ksadmin1
    fi
```